# statusCode property not set AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: afnetworking

I am using the following code to make a http request and get json response back from a server. However when I look at the response's statusCode, I get the error that statusCode property is not set. What needs to be done to set the statusCode property in response.

```
NSString * my_url_string = @"http://link-to-my-server";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:my_url_string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
       if (response.statusCode == 200){
        //I GET AN AERROR THAT statusCode IS NOT SET
```

Answer (score 0):

Error notwithstanding, AFNetworking already made the check for a successful status code with its success/failure completion block distinction. That is to say, unless you want to differentiate between different successful status codes (200, 201, 204, etc.), you don't need to do this check yourself.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. I have a REST api, which returns 204 when there is no more data for that user. It returns 200 only when there is data for the requesting user.

I need to look at the response statusCode, and take different actions for 200 and 204.

Comment: If you get a 204, `responseData` and `responseString` will both be `nil`.  To put it more simply, just check if you have data to determine whether you have data.